# formate date as per my requirement

Tags: iphone, nsdate

I want  to make date by date formatter 
`2012-07-12` but it display like
`2012-07-11`
My code:

```
  NString * today_selected=[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%d%@%d%@%d",year_for_activated,@"-",month_for_activated,@"-",taged];      NSDateFormatter *Df=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
```

//here year_of_=2012 and month_of_ac=7, and tag=12

but it display 2012-07-11 instead of 12.

```
  [Df setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-DD" ];
  NSDate *date_selected=[Df dateFromString: today_selected];
  NSLog(@"today_selected:%@",date_selected);
```

but it display 2012-01-12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try this:
NString *today_selected=@"2012-07-12";
NSDateFormatter *Df=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[Df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd" ];
NSDate *date_selected=[Df dateFromString: today_selected];
NSLog(@"today_selected:%@",date_selected);
```

Comment: We are all here with the hope of learning something. Please try to post answers which explain where the person posting the question has gone wrong and that way it will help them understand and learn and will aid people who are searching in the future.

Answer (score 5):

Please read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1) which states

> It uses yyyy to specify the year component. A common mistake is to use
>   YYYY. yyyy specifies the calendar year whereas YYYY specifies the year
>   (of "Week of Year"), used in the ISO year-week calendar. In most
>   cases, yyyy and YYYY yield the same number, however they may be
>   different. Typically you should use the calendar year.

Also you will note that the day is `dd`, NOT `DD`

When you find a problem like this, your first stop should be the documentation

Answer (score 1):

try this for get the 2012-07-12 ,this type of Formatter :

```
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

  NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];

  NSString *theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:now];
```

Comment: But this does not match the formatting that @user1506533 wants.

Comment: We are all here with the hope of learning something. Please try to post answers which explain where the person posting the question has gone wrong and that way it will help them understand and learn and will aid people who are searching in the future.